# Is it correct to call something an "objective speculation"?

Tags: meaning

I'm currently writing a review for a book for school, and I'm having some trouble as to how I should express that event though I may show some bias, I can provide an "objective speculation." Is this the correct way to say that?

Comment: are you speculating or are you assessing?

Comment: Oops, it seems like I'm assessing. @Jim

Comment: Without having any specifics, ... No one is perfectly objective. If you're trying to be objective then that's all anyone can ask. If you have something that causes you to look at things in a certain way you can say what that is.

Comment: This is less a question of English language than a question about Mathematics and statistical logic.

Comment: What do you mean by *speculation*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To speculate" means "Reasoning based on inconclusive evidence; conjecture or supposition".  I think it would be difficult to be objective about that, since "objective" means "Uninfluenced by emotions or personal prejudices".

Your best bet would be to not use the two words together:  "although I do have some bias in this matter, I would speculate that ......".

Even that may not be persuasive for the reader.

Comment: Don't agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a mathematical and engineering background, we do perform objective speculation.

Statistics is nothing more than objective speculation, educated guesses. However, in the science of statistical design, we need to be objective in the parameters we feed in.

What is the probability density of a manufacturing pipeline carrying a failing item. At which point of the pipeline is that density the highest. At that point we should place more stringent monitors or higher sampling. Objectively, without relying on hearsay or emotional attachments, provide the objective parameters on which we need to speculate the dynamically shifting locations of failures on the pipeline at any given time window.

Therefore, if you are writing a report for engineering, business or economic analysis, where educated speculation is necessarily practiced, you would do well with having objective speculation.

Comment: Agree with you.